# Dynamic MySQL commands through Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know of a Javascript + MySQL script that will allow me to dynamically request mysql information through javascript instead of having to make a seperate php file for each individual Ajax request i have?

I ask since I made a dynamic script that will insert MySQL info, and was curious if there was already one out there that can request it.

I hear that this idea could cause a security problem. Any ideas how to still make this possible? I have many AJAX requests and I don't want to make tens if not hundreds small PHP scripts for this...

Thanks!

Comment: Trusting the client to construct queries to your server-side database has some security implications ...

Comment: What if rather than dynamically creating full queries, you instead send some options in the request, and then on the PHP side (in one file) validate the options and build the query? `{"table": "your_table", "where": {"foo": "bar", "snow": "beer"}, "order": "snow ASC"}`

Comment: Check this out. This is my dynamic function to send mysql data mysql('pages',{
    check: 'id',
    id: page_id,
       
    meta_title: value
}); 
So exactly as you say hookedonwinter, I send values and options. Not the whole query. You guys know of a function that works like mine but the other way round?

Comment: `mysql('users', ['password', 'username'])`... Is this *really* what you want?

Comment: The Javascript runs on the client side, in the user's browser. The user has full control over it. The user can query your database any way he likes. Is there no data whatsoever in the database that the user better *not* have access to?

Comment: Isn't there some clever, suphisticated way which i can use to make this possible by encrypting, using sessions, or passwords to ensure that the user does not have full control over the database?

Comment: Yes, it's called an API that is server-side and has full control over the data the client gets to see. Anything that is happening client-side is under the full control of the user. By definition there's no security you can apply. You can't give the client control and at the same time not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! By using hashes. I can simply add an md5 to the ajax (the md5 will contain the string info + some random code, this will be created using a php script). Then the script that actually inserts or requests the info from the database (php) will attempt to create the same md5 hash. If it is successfull, it is legit, if not, then stop the database request or post.

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=391